# Bride and groom for photo

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange seven people in arow, including the bride and the groom, if the bride must be next to the groom?**

Here is my attempt at solving this problem.

Since there are 7 people and 2 of the seven are the bride and groom. The bride and groom must be next to each other. So we can consider them as one person. This leaves 6 people left. The bride and groom can be arranged 2 different ways. The six people can be arranged 6! Different ways. So in total 2*6!.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. @Phillip